# How to tackle atomic transaction in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, transactions, database

I have a store where **item price** is determined based on the **quantity** available, so whenever user request items, I have to **calculate price** based on the **requested quantity**

I have to implement **price calculation in an atomic way** so that if a transaction occurs during calculation of an ongoing transaction and the **price** or **availableQuantity** changes, it should not **affect** both transactions.

**Initial Database**

```
{
   "_id": "1",
   "availableQuantity": 10,
   "pricePerItem": 15
},
{
   "_id": "2",
   "availableQuantity": 5,
   "pricePerItem": 10
},
{
   "_id": "3",
   "availableQuantity": 6,
   "pricePerItem": 20
}
```

It means that
I can sell **5** items with price ***10 / item***
next **10** items with price ***15 / item***
next **6** items with price ***20 / item***

#### senario:

User **"A"** wants to buy 8 items, price will be calculated like this
First, the minimum price object will be selected in our case it is **_Id: "2"**
**5** items will be taken from this object then **price = 10*5 = 50**

***updated database***

```
{
   "_id": "1",
   "availableQuantity": 10,
   "pricePerItem": 15
},
{
   "_id": "3",
   "availableQuantity": 6,
   "pricePerItem": 20
}
```

Remaining **3** items will be taken from minimum price object which is **_id: "1"**
Price for **3** items will be **price = 3*15 = 45**

Total price for user **"A"**  **8** items will be **total price = 50 + 45 = 95**

**Final Database**

```
{
   "_id": "1",
   "availableQuantity": 7,
   "pricePerItem": 15
},
{
   "_id": "3",
   "availableQuantity": 6,
   "pricePerItem": 20
}
```

### Problem

During user **"A"** transaction if user **"B"** is requesting **4** items then how should we determine the correct prices.

**Note:** Many transactions are expected to happen simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb does not have support for transactions. There are not-so-popular npm packages which imitate transactional behaviour on the application level but that's it :(